# My first calculator JS

Tags: javascript

Hello I've started learning javascript and today made my first calculator
I would like to hear any suggestions how could I did it better and good coding practices.

```
// Inputs fields used in program 
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
let screen = document.getElementById('output');
let history = document.getElementById('last');


// Arrays of operators and numbers
const operator = ['/', '*' , '+' ,'-']; 
const numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'];

// Flags 
let currentNumber;
let currentOperator;
let equalClicked = false;
let operatorUsed = false;

let calculator = function() {

    let value = this.value; // Value of current button being pressed 

    if ( operator.includes(value) && operatorUsed == false ){ // Checks if its operator and check if it wasn't used two times in a row
        if(equalClicked){ // it works that after pressing '=' and then one of the operators it's doing :
        history.value = result(); // inserting previous result
        history.value += value ; // and current operator 
        }
        else{
        history.value += screen.value;
        history.value += value ;
        }
        operatorUsed = true; // Set that operator was used
        currentOperator = value; // Store current operator which is needed for clicking '=' multiple times
        equalClicked = false; // Reseting '=' clicked so now we again perform operations

    }
    else if (numbers.includes(value)){ // Checks if current button is one of numbers stored in array
        if (screen.value == 0 || operatorUsed == true ){ // It worsk so the output(screen) previous value is being replaced
            screen.value = value;
            operatorUsed = false;
        }
        else{ // adding 2 digits and more numbers like 22, 123 etc.
            screen.value += value;
        }
        currentNumber = value; // Store current number which is needed for clicking '=' multiple times

    }
    else if (value == 'C'){ // Clearing the screen and the history fields
        history.value =''
        screen.value = 0;
    }
    else if (value == '='){ 
        if (equalClicked == false){
            history.value += screen.value ;
            screen.value = result();
            equalClicked = true;
        }
        else{ // Clicking '=' multiple times
            history.value = screen.value + currentOperator + currentNumber;
            screen.value = result();
        }

    }
};


function result(){ // Function which calculate and return result 
    return eval(history.value);
}

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { // setting addEventListener for all elements that have class buttons
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', calculator);
}
```

Here is also html code for that is someone would like test it :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="box">
        
            <input type='text' class='screen' id='output' value='0'>
            <input type='text' class='history' id='last'>
            
            <div class='buttons-wrapper'>
                <button class='buttons' value="7" >7</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="8" >8</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="9" >9</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="/" >/</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="4" >4</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="5" >5</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="6" >6</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="*" >*</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="1" >1</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="2" >2</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="3" >3</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="+" >+</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="." >.</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="0" >0</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="C" >C</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="-" >-</button>
                <button class='buttons' value="=" >=</button>
                
            </div>
        
        </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Title improvements are welcome, my first calculator was already taken and hence blocked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the JavaScript World! You have a lot to learn and that's really cool :-).

Here are a few tips.

---

**Naming**

Try to use more explicit names. I never regretted spending time finding better names for my variables and functions.

For example:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
```

Could be (a little bit better but I'm sure you can find better):

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
```

---

**Split your function into smaller ones.**

This helps readability and code reuse.

For example:

```
if (operator.includes(value) && operatorUsed == false) {
    // ...
}
```

Can be extracted:

```
function isOperator (value) {
    return operator.includes(value) && operatorUsed == false
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
if (isOperator(value)) {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Don't repeat yourself**

For example:

```
if (equalClicked) { // it works that after pressing '=' and then one of the operators it's doing :
    history.value = result() // inserting previous result
    history.value += value  // and current operator
} else {
    history.value += screen.value
    history.value += value
}
```

In both cases you do:

```
history.value += value
```

So just do it once at after the if statement:

```
if (equalClicked) {
    history.value = result()
} else {
    history.value += screen.value
}
history.value += value
```

---

**Style guide**

The style of your code is not consistent (parentheses, alignments). I suggest you to search for "JavaScript style Guide" in Google.

Do not overuse comments (this is a personal taste): I think if you code with short functions and good names, you don't need comments.

---

I changed your code following these advices (I haven't changed anything about the logic):

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons')
let screen = document.getElementById('output')
let history = document.getElementById('last')

const operator = ['/', '*', '+', '-']
const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

let currentNumber
let currentOperator
let equalClicked = false
let operatorUsed = false




function handleInput () {

    let value = this.value

    if (isOperator(value)) {
        insertOperator(value)
    } else if (isNumber(value)) {
        insertNumber(value)
    } else if (isClear(value)) {
        clear()
    } else if (isEqual(value)) {
        calculate()
    }

}




function isOperator (value) {
    return operator.includes(value) && operatorUsed == false
}

function isNumber (value) {
    return numbers.includes(value)
}

function isClear (value) {
    return value == 'C'
}

function isEqual (value) {
    return value == '='
}




function insertOperator (value) {
    if (equalClicked) {
        history.value = evalResult()
    } else {
        history.value += screen.value
    }

    history.value += value
    operatorUsed = true
    currentOperator = value
    equalClicked = false
}


function calculate () {
    if (equalClicked == false) {
        history.value += screen.value
        equalClicked = true
    } else {
        history.value = screen.value + currentOperator + currentNumber
    }

    screen.value = evalResult()
}


function insertNumber (value) {
    if (screen.value == 0 || operatorUsed == true) {
        screen.value = value
        operatorUsed = false
    } else {
        screen.value += value
    }
    currentNumber = value
}


function clear () {
    history.value = ''
    screen.value = 0
}





function evalResult () {
    return eval(history.value)
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', handleInput)
}
```

---

**About the logic**

You use raw string inputs and you concatenate them before passing them to javascript eval, which is a smart move but I think, is bug prone and not reliable if you want to go further.

I suggest you to cast string inputs into javascript numbers and map operators into real javascript functions.

For example:

```
function add (numberA, numberB) {
    return numberA + numberB
}

if (operator === '+') {
    const newValue = add(currentValue, parseInt(inputValue, 10))
}
```

Have fun

Comment: such a useful tips and stuff thanks a lot !